# Is nullable double and decimal update atomic on x64 system?

Tags: c#, atomic

In most cases `double` and `decimal` type update on 64 bit system is an atomic operation cause these types are 64 bit. (decimal is 128bit so this is wrong, thanks for comments)

But when I update `double?` and `decimal?` type on 64 bit system will it be atomic? What is the size of `double?` and `decimal?`

I understand that atomicity is not guaranteed though I still interested if such update will be atomic in general scenario.

Comment: in any circumstance when atomicity is being discussed, it is **critical** what is *guaranteed*. If (as you state) atomicity is not guaranteed, then frankly **that is the end of the discussion**. Anything past that is moot and irrelevent: you can't trust it, so don't use it.

Comment: A `Decimal` in .NET is 128 bits, not 64 bit. Updating a `decimal` on a 64bit system is therefore **not** atomic.

Comment: Technically, even the update to `double` is not guaranteed. I would probably use `Interlocked` to talk **even to that** - or a `lock` etc.

Comment: @MarcGravell disagree. atomicity is guaranteed on my server using particular OS and particular framework version and particular application. If this is the only scenario i'm going to use the application why not benefit from atomicity?

Comment: @javapowered and who made you that guarantee? You won't find it in the language spec. What you mean is: "I deduce this is ok" - that is ***not*** a guarantee

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In most cases double and decimal type update on 64 bit system is atomic operation cause these types are 64 bit.

No, `decimal` is 128 bit to start with. Also note that running on a 64-bit *computer* doesn't necessarily mean you're running the 64-bit CLR. It's not clear what you mean by "system" here.

So you shouldn't even assume atomicity for `decimal`. Even on a 64-bit CLR, I wouldn't want to rely on the atomicity of `double`, partly as it will depend on alignment. The C# specification explicitly states (section 5.5 of the C# 4 spec):

> Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic.

So that makes the nullable side kinda pointless, but...

> But when I update double? and decimal? type on 64 bit system will it be atomic? what is the size of double? and decimal?

`Nullable<T>` is basically a `T` field and a `bool` field. So the storage will be more than 64 bits for `double`, and more than 128 bits for `decimal`. The exact storage will quite possibly depend on the context, but basically I *wouldn't* expect atomicity for operations with these types.

As others have said, you almost certainly don't want to rely on anything that's not guaranteed. Personally I'd almost always try to avoid lock-free coding in general. Try to use higher-level abstractions that are provided by the CLR/BCL teams and proven to be safe.

Comment: "Personally I'd almost always try to avoid lock-free coding in general." - spoilsport ;p (that is tongue in cheek; when I delve into lock-free, I take a strong coffee first)

Comment: I am curious though, if you are running on an x86 CPU, as a 64bit process, are 64 bit value types / structs atomically written?  C# specification is deliberately loose, but I don't see why in a 64bit x86 context it wouldn't be atomic.

Comment: Sorry about `decimal`. Ok on my system (HP DL360p-Gen8, Windows Server 2008 R2, .NET Framework 4.5) `double` update IS atomic. and `double?` update is NOT atomic? I just need to know how things work *on*my*particular*configuration. I do not need portability, i need speed. As speed = money for me and portability = nothing.

Comment: also I was using `double?` in my system prety intensive without any locks. As `double?` type is more than 64 bit than it just can not be atomic, right? I just wonder how my system works then without any problems. Any chance to have `double?` update atomic? Probably I just need to write the test...

Comment: Given that reads and writes of long, ulong, double, and decimal are not atomic, what happens when you try to read and write them at the same time in multiple threads *without locking*? Can you actually read out nonsensical values or completely fail a read/write (resulting in an immediate Exception)?

Comment: @Kal: In theory you could read values that haven't been written (not necessarily "nonsensical" ones, just ones with part of one value and part of another). Actually demonstrating this phenomenon (known as "tearing") is likely to be tricky - you could probably do it more easily with your own very large custom struct.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is it possible that assignment to a Nullable<T> would be thread-safe by accident? I used ILSpy to look at the decompiled source code of Nullable<T> and there's an implicit conversion, which means that every time you assign to a Nullable<T>, you are actually creating a new Nullable<T> first, instead of overwriting the internal value in the existing Nullable<T>. Now, because Nullable<T> is not your run-of-the-mill struct (it can be null), is it possible that the CLR actually uses a pointer or address for it, which is in fact updated atomically?

Comment: @JonSkeet I also wrote a simple WPF program to test the tearing effect on a ulong. It was really easy to get the tearing with a regular ulong, but so far I have had no luck getting tearing with a Nullable<ulong>.

Answer (score 4):

> I understand that atomicity is not guaranteed

That's it. It is not guaranteed.

> I still interested if such update will be atomic in general scenario.

It is not guaranteed.

Just like [Marc said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362069/is-nullable-double-and-decimal-update-atomic-on-x64-system/13362098#comment18241063_13362069).

Comment: i've learned that using HP DL360p-Gen 8, Windows Server 2008 R2 and .NET Framework 4.5 atomicity is guaranteed. This is the only scenario I need.

Comment: @javapowered - That is far from what you described in your question, and it is still **not** guaranteed. That it appears to work atomically, doesn't make it so.

Comment: Of course it is guaranteed on *this* configuration. You will not be able to run it *not* atomic on *this* configuration.

Comment: @javapowered - What are you talking about? A `decimal` is 128 bits - operations on it _cannot_ be atomic on a 64bit architecture. Where exactly did you get this guarantee? Who from?

Comment: I'm talking about 64-it types such as `double`. I've made a mistake in my initial question.

Comment: @javapowered - I did answer the original question, so in that respect, the answer is still correct. It is also correct in regards to nullables.

Answer (score 1):

C# specificaiton allows it to write a 64 bit variable as two 32 bit variables.

> The C# language reserves the right to make writing to a long
>   equivalent to writing to two ints, one after the other, and in
>   practice some chips do implement it that way

See more for Eric Lippert [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628660/1252687)