# Is C# += thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Just ran into a program where += is used on a shared variable among threads, so is += thread safe, i.e. performs addition and assignment atomically?

Comment: No, it's not. It's writing to a variable.

Comment: No.  It's reading, doing the addition, and then writing to the variable.  It is not atomic.

Comment: Autoincrement needs to be interlocked to be thread-safe.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628243/is-the-operator-thread-safe?rq=1. And the answer is Never

Answer (score 12):

No it isn't thread safe since it's equivalent to:

```
int temp = orig + value;
orig = temp;
```

You can use [`Interlocked.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33821kfh.aspx) instead:

```
Interlocked.Add(ref orig, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
System.Threading.Interlocked.Add()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s += "foo";
```

is

```
string s = s + "foo";
```

`s` is read and then re-assigned. If in between these two actions the value of `s` is changed by another thread, the result with be different, so it's not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the quick replies. Yes, += is not thread safe and to verify this one may run the following simple program.

`int count = 0;`

```
        Parallel.For(0, 10000, i =>
        {
            count +=1; // not thread safe
        });
        Console.WriteLine(count);
```