# How to get the amount of threads waiting to enter a lock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

Is it possible to get a value which indicates how many threads are waiting to acquire a lock on a certain object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could incapsulate the lock in a class that does:

```
Interlocked.Increment
```

before entering the lock on a counter and

```
Interlocked.Decrement
```

after attaining the lock

For example:

```
public sealed class SimpleCountedLock
{
    private readonly object obj = new object();

    private int counter;

    public int Counter
    {
        get
        {
            // Guaranteed to return the last value
            return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref counter, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void Enter(ref bool lockTaken)
    {
        int cnt = int.MinValue;

        try
        {
            try
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                // Finally code can't be interrupted by asyncronous exceptions
                cnt = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
            }

            Monitor.Enter(obj, ref lockTaken);
        }
        finally
        {
            // There could be an asynchronous exception (Thread.Abort for example)
            // between the try and the Interlocked.Increment .
            // Here we check if the Increment was done
            if (cnt != int.MinValue)
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}
```

Use:

```
SimpleCountedLock cl = new SimpleCountedLock();
```

and then in the various threads:

```
bool lockTaken = false;

try
{
    cl.Enter(ref lockTaken);
    // Your code. The lock is taken
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        cl.Exit();
    }
}
```

The reasoning for the ref lockTaken is here: [Monitor.Enter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It appears not; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628243/is-the-operator-thread-safe

Comment: @toplel32 Yep, `++` and `--` aren't thread safe, nor is reading 64 bit values (`long`) when your app is 32 bits

Comment: @toplel32 Fixed the typo :-)

Comment: Is the `Finally` block crucial for the `Interlock.Increment` call? If so, is there an uniform way to solve the problem?

Comment: @toplel32 If you aren't interested in the counter being "exact" in case of asyncronous exceptions (consider that only `Thread.Abort ` doesn't kill the program, the other two async exceptions are "very bad errors" that will always kill the program), then you can remove all the try... except of the `Enter` method.