# I am getting a TaskCanceledException in a Parallel.ForEach loop, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I am running a `Parallel.ForEach` in C#. I am getting below `TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled`. Can anyone suggest where I can fix my Task cancellation, or increase my connection timeout?

My code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var SQLServerName = "XXXXXXXXXX.database.windows.net";
    var SQLServerAdmin = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    var SQLServerAdminPasword = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    var DatabaseName = "XXXXXXXXXX";

    string SQLStatement = ($"DELETE FROM ResourceStatus WHERE ResourceType = 'RBAC' " +
        $"TRUNCATE TABLE RBACStaging ");
    Helper.ExecuteTSQL(SQLServerName, SQLServerAdmin, SQLServerAdminPasword,
        DatabaseName, SQLStatement);

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

    builder.DataSource = SQLServerName;
    builder.UserID = SQLServerAdmin;
    builder.Password = SQLServerAdminPasword;
    builder.InitialCatalog = DatabaseName;
    List<string> Subscriptions = new List<string>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append($"SELECT SubscriptionID from Subscriptions " +
            $"where SOX = 'SR0' and Environment = 'Prod'");
        string sql = sb.ToString();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    Subscriptions.Add(Reader.GetString(0).ToString());
                }
                connection.Close();
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(connection);
            }
        }
    }
    Parallel.ForEach(Subscriptions, s =>
    {
        string SubscriptionID = s.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
        RBACSnapshot.GetRBACSnapshot(SubscriptionID).Wait();
    });
}
```

`GetRBACSnapshot` method:

```
public static async Task GetRBACSnapshot(string SubscriptionID)
{
    var ClientID = "de9f7784-93e4-42d0-a68d-7f1457ce4e56";
    var AppKey = "XXXXXXXX";
    var SQLServerName = "XXXXXXXX.database.windows.net";
    var SQLServerAdmin = "XXXXXXXX";
    var SQLServerAdminPasword = "XXXXXXXX";
    var DatabaseName = "XXXXXXXX";
    string TenantID = null;
    string ServiceGroupName = null;
    string TeamGroupName = null;
    string ServiceName = null;
    string ServiceTreeID = null;
    string Level = null;
    string SOX = null;
    string SubscriptionName = null;
    string EnvironmentScope = null;
    string Tenant = null;

    DateTime RawDate = DateTime.Now;
    string RefreshedAt = RawDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
    string SQLStatement = null;
    SQLStatement = ($"INSERT INTO ResourceStatus " +
                    $"SELECT 'RBAC', '{SubscriptionID}', 'Started', '{RefreshedAt}'");
    Helper.ExecuteTSQL(SQLServerName, SQLServerAdmin, SQLServerAdminPasword,
        DatabaseName, SQLStatement);

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

    builder.DataSource = SQLServerName;
    builder.UserID = SQLServerAdmin;
    builder.Password = SQLServerAdminPasword;
    builder.InitialCatalog = DatabaseName;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append($"SELECT ServiceGroupName, TeamGroupName, ServiceName, " +
            $"ServiceTreeID, Level, SOX, SubscriptionName, Environment, Tenant " +
            $"from Subscriptions where SubscriptionID = '{SubscriptionID}'");
        string sql = sb.ToString();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    ServiceGroupName = Reader.GetString(0).ToString();
                    TeamGroupName = Reader.GetString(1).ToString();
                    ServiceName = Reader.GetString(2).ToString();
                    ServiceTreeID = Reader.GetString(3).ToString();
                    Level = Reader.GetString(4).ToString();
                    SOX = Reader.GetString(5).ToString();
                    SubscriptionName = Reader.GetString(6).ToString();
                    EnvironmentScope = Reader.GetString(7).ToString();
                    Tenant = Reader.GetString(8).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
        SqlConnection.ClearPool(connection);
    }

    // AARE Logic
    if (Tenant.Equals("AME", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        TenantID = "33e01921-4d64-4f8c-a055-5bdaffd5e33d";
    }
    else if (Tenant.Equals("GME", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        TenantID = "124edf19-b350-4797-aefc-3206115ffdb3";
    }
    else if (Tenant.Equals("PME", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        TenantID = "975f013f-7f24-47e8-a7d3-abc4752bf346";
    }
    else if (Tenant.Equals("Corp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        TenantID = "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47";
    }
    string AzToken = await Helper.GetAccessTokenAsync(TenantID, ClientID, AppKey);
    string MSGraphToken = await Helper.GetGraphAccessToken(TenantID, ClientID, AppKey)
        .ConfigureAwait(true);

    var httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
    };
    string URI = $"{SubscriptionID}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?" +
        $"api-version=2018-09-01-preview";
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AzToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var HttpsResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(HttpsResponse);

    if (Result["value"] != null)
    {
        foreach (dynamic item in Result["value"])
        {
            string ObjectID = item.properties.principalId;
            string ObjectType = item.properties.principalType;
            string ObjectCategory = null;

            if (ObjectType.Equals("ServicePrincipal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                ObjectCategory = "servicePrincipals";
            }

            else if (ObjectType.Equals("User", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                ObjectCategory = "users";
            }

            else if (ObjectType.Equals("Group", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                ObjectCategory = "groups";
            }

            string AccessScope = item.properties.scope;
            string DisplayName = await Helper.GetDisplayName(TenantID, ObjectID,
                MSGraphToken, ObjectCategory);
            string RoleDefinitionIDFullText = item.properties.roleDefinitionId;
            string RoleDefinitionID = RoleDefinitionIDFullText.Substring(
                RoleDefinitionIDFullText.Length - 36);
            string AccessLevel = await Helper.GetRoleDefinitionName(RoleDefinitionID,
                SubscriptionID, AzToken);
            string ProvisionedByObjID = item.properties.createdBy;
            string ProvisionedBy = await Helper.GetDisplayName(TenantID,
                ProvisionedByObjID, MSGraphToken, "Decide");
            string ProvisionedAt = item.properties.createdOn;
            string Compliant = Helper.ComplianceValidation(SOX, EnvironmentScope,
                DisplayName, ObjectType, AccessLevel, ProvisionedBy, AccessScope);
            RawDate = DateTime.Now;
            RefreshedAt = RawDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            string Action = null;
            if (Compliant.Equals("Yes"))
            {
                Action = "No Action Needed";
            }
            else if (Compliant.Equals("No"))
            {
                Action = "Revoke";
            }
            else
            {
                Action = "Yet To Decide";
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{ServiceGroupName}, {TeamGroupName}, {ServiceName}, " +
                $"{ServiceTreeID}, {Level}, {SOX}, {SubscriptionName}, {SubscriptionID}, " +
                $"{EnvironmentScope}, {Tenant}, {DisplayName}, {ObjectType}, {ObjectID}, " +
                $"{AccessLevel}, {ProvisionedBy}, {ProvisionedAt}, {AccessScope}, " +
                $"{Compliant}, {Action}, {ProvisionedByObjID}, {RefreshedAt}"); ;

            SQLStatement = ($"INSERT INTO RBACStaging Select '{ServiceGroupName}'," +
                $"'{TeamGroupName}','{ServiceName}','{ServiceTreeID}','{Level}','{SOX}'" +
                $",'{SubscriptionName}','{SubscriptionID}','{EnvironmentScope}'," +
                $"'{Tenant}','{DisplayName}','{ObjectType}','{ObjectID}','{AccessLevel}'," +
                $"'{ProvisionedBy}','{ProvisionedAt}','{AccessScope}','{Compliant}'," +
                $"'{Action}','{ProvisionedByObjID}','{RefreshedAt}'");
            try
            {
                Helper.ExecuteTSQL(SQLServerName, SQLServerAdmin, SQLServerAdminPasword,
                    DatabaseName, SQLStatement);
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sqlException.Message);
            }
        }
    } // End of IF Condition to check Null value from Rest API Calls.
    RawDate = DateTime.Now;
    RefreshedAt = RawDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
    SQLStatement = ($"update ResourceStatus Set Status = 'Completed', " +
        $"LastUpdatedTime = '{RefreshedAt}' where ResourceType = 'RBAC' and " +
        $"SubscriptionID = '{SubscriptionID}'");
    Helper.ExecuteTSQL(SQLServerName, SQLServerAdmin, SQLServerAdminPasword,
        DatabaseName, SQLStatement);
} // End of Method
```

The exception:

```
TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IList`1 list, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
   at CPXFundamentals.Program.Main() in C:\Users\venkatag\source\repos\CPXFundamentals\Program.cs:line 47
```

Comment: As a side note the `N++;` [is not thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628243/is-the-operator-thread-safe), and you are calling it inside the body of a parallel loop.

Comment: Regarding your main question, we need to see the `RBACSnapshot.GetRBACSnapshot` method before being able to provide any useful advice.

Comment: This is really not the way to parallelize async functions anyway, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda

Comment: Theodor Zoulias: I added the GETRBACSnapshot Method. 
Can someone please tell me how to fix the Task Cancelled issue.

Comment: I added both my Main Method and GetRBACSnapshot Method

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider just catching any `TaskCanceledException`s if you have no access to the implementation of `GetRBACSnapshot`.

For example you could catch the `TaskCanceledException` and add that subscription back into a queue to be retried at a later time.

Just be sure not to consume all errors, and solely consume `TaskCanceledException`. You should avoid unintentionally consuming critical runtime errors.

Something similar to this might work for you:

```cs
int N = 1;
Parallel.ForEach(Subscriptions, s =>
{
    string SubscriptionID = s.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine($"Working on {N}. {SubscriptionID}");
    
    try
    {
        RBACSnapshot.GetRBACSnapshot(SubscriptionID).Wait();
        Interlocked.Increment(ref N);
    }
    catch(TaskCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{SubscriptionID} Timed out");
        // do something else like add it back to a queue to be tried again
        // just make sure any collection you add the subscription to is thread safe
    }
});
```

Comment: I suspect `OperationCancelledException` is a typo.

Comment: Lmao it sure is