# ActionBlock misses actions sometimes

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, tpl-dataflow

I'm using `ActionBlock` and I tested if it's working properly like below and sometime `Actionblock` misses actions and it shouldn't happen at all

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

```
var n = 0;
var action = new Action<int>((i) =>
{
    n++;

    //...job...
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    var block = new ActionBlock<int>(i => action(i),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 6 });

    n = 0;

    foreach (var a in list)
        block.Post(a);

    block.Complete();
    block.Completion.Wait();

    if (n != list.Count)
        ShowError();   //it's called sometimes
}
```

Comment: Related: [Is the ++ operator thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628243/is-the-operator-thread-safe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionBlock` can execute operations in parallel manner (and I believe it does exactly this in your case). So, in this case you just have a data race on `n++` operation.
So, actually the `ActionBlock` does not miss anything, but you just calculating `n` incorrectly and sometimes (may be almost all the time) get incorrect count at the end.

To get correct value of `n` you may replace `n++` with `Interlocked.Increment(ref n)` or just add a `lock`.