# Why is this Loop Working Infinitely

Tags: c#, loops

This is a simple while loop in C# but it is working infinitely.

```
int count = 1;
while (count < 10)
{
    count = count++;
}
```

Why is this so?

Comment: ++count will give the the desired action.

Comment: in my opinion this question does not deserve upVotes, just my idea, the code in the question shows not understanding of ++ post operator...

Comment: tip: try debugging it...

Comment: @Jordan: If he replaces the line by `count = ++count;`, as you suggested, the code will work, but it will *still be broken*.

Comment: I concur with @AI25. Debugging is something you should be doing prior to asking others for help. Perhaps you could have asked, "How might I debug this code?" You could attempt to view what the value of `count` is, I'm certain this will help you narrow down what you're doing. Or even open up a console in firebug and try it out with JavaScript.

Comment: This assign (`count = count++;`) makes no sense. Write clean code and it will work: `count++;`

Comment: Are you serious? How did this question get so many upvotes? Sometimes stackoverflow does my head in.

Comment: <get off my lawn>What a ludicrous amount of voting relative to more useful posts...</get off my lawn>

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This will loop infinitely.

There are two types of incrementing a variable:

Here `count++` and `++count`  both are different if you have used `++count`  it will work.

Here `count = count++` means count variable will be incremented by one then assigns the earlier value 1 to the count variable itself so count remains unchanged.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier please check it with count = ++count you can see it works!

Comment: @Mad: I removed my comments, I thought this was a C++ question, please forgive my inattention. Thanks.

Answer (score 58):

The expression `count++` returns the original value of count, then increments the value afterwards.

So you are overwriting count with the same value every time.  Just do this:

```
count++;
```

For the curious, here's a link to Eric Lippert's article which distinguishes between operator precedence and the order of evaluation -- it's an interesting read:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/10/precedence-vs-order-redux.aspx

Comment: +1 for both explaining why `count = count++;` causes a problem and that the solution is simple `count++` without assignment.

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with operator precedence. In addition, saying "afterwards" is not accurate: The value is incremented and *then* a value is returned, it just happens to be that the *old* value is returned, see [this answer by Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729) for details.

Comment: Good point, I removed the mention of operator precedence.  And you get an upvote from me.  :)

Answer (score 27):

`count  = count++;` does *not* increment `count` by one. `x++` is the *post* increment operator, which means that the value returned by the expression is the *old* value. Thus, in your code, the following happens:

```
int oldValue = count;
count = count + 1;
count = oldValue;
```

What you probably meant to write was `count++;` (without the "`count =`").

More details about this can be found in the following SO question:

- [What does "count++" return in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5030653/87698)

Answer (score 7):

The ++ operator first saves the current value then increments and finally returns the saved value, so `count` will never change.

Eiter use the `++` operator or do an assignment. These are all equivalent:

```
count++;
count += 1;
count = count + 1;
```

Comment: That is not what the ++ operator does. It first *saves the current value*, then it increments, then it returns the saved value. It does not return the value *before* it does the increment.

Comment: @EricLippert: Why it returns the saved value? It incremented the value then it should return the incremented value, right? Also, does count++ will return count? How?

Comment: @Gator: The post-increment operator increments the variable and returns the non-incremented value. The pre-increment operator increments the variable and returns the incremented value.

Comment: @Gator: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729 for more details.

Answer (score 5):

```
count  = count++;
```

This is a post-increment. It does the following.

```
int temp = count;
count++;
count = temp;
```

So you're not incrementing count. Use the following instead:

```
while (count  < 10)
{
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: Here you said that count++. And then you are saying that its not incrementing count??? Isnt count++ is equal to count = count + 1 ? You should saying we are not incrementing temp!

Answer (score 1):

because

```
count++
```

returns `count`, not `count + 1`

just have count++ with no assignment or:

```
count = ++count;
```

the last one only to explain but you should not use it...

from: [++ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx)

> The first form is a prefix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand after it has been incremented.
>
> The second form is a postfix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand before it has been incremented.
>
> Numeric and enumeration types have predefined increment operators.
>   User-defined types can overload the ++ operator. Operations on
>   integral types are generally allowed on enumeration.

Comment: Why count++ will return count? I think count++ is equal to count = count + 1?

Comment: @Gator count++ returns count if you assign it, while ++count return (count + 1). Check the difference between ++i and i++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is infinite because you aren't actually incrementing count.

count = count++; assigns the value of 1 to count and then increments count but since you don't assign the incremented value count never increases.

You need to do either:

```
count++;
```

or

```
count = ++count;
```

Comment: No, never do "count = ++count"

Answer (score 0):

Let me ask you a question why do you make two operations on a single variable while one is enough?
what was your intention? count++ itself was enough so why again assign to count. May be you want to do something else.
You could have only count++, or ++count or count+1. I think other ways causes two operations.
Sorry for my way of writing.