# a = i++; does `a` equal `i`?

Tags: c

In this code snippet, what values do `a` and `i`  have respectively and why?

```
int i = 1;
int a = i++;
```

Does `a == 1` or `a == 2` ?

Comment: You can answer the first part of the question by simply running the program

Comment: This is one of those things best tried rather than asking on here. It is called the postfix operator, and it happens after the assignment. So `a == 1` and `i == 2`.

Comment: Or even by thinking. I'm surprised someone with 4K rep would ask this.

Comment: effort required in typing the question could have been better used to type code and test

Comment: @all, Don't have a c compiler here and I need to translate a piece of code into assembler.

Comment: @Johan If you have internet access, you do have a C compiler.

Comment: Relevant reading: [C#: what is the difference between i++ and ++i?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729) (not C, but still interesting)

Comment: @Neil, good point I don't know you I didn't think of that. I wonder if there's an online c-compiler that I can throw snippets into to see what code comes out. Yes, found it: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/

Comment: Try this one: http://ideone.com/n0W5X

Comment: @Kobi, great link, works like a charm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a==1`. And then, `i==2`

It would be `a==2` if you did `a=++i`

Answer (score 5):

A will be one. This is called a post-increment. The variable i is only increased after being used. The opposite is called a pre-increment.

Answer (score 2):

`a==1`, `i++` returns the value of `i` and then increments it. FYI, if you had `++i` the opposite would be true, `i` would be incremented and then the value would be returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 1;
```

`i` now has the value 1.

```
int a = i++;
```

`a` has the value of `i++`, which is `1` (`i++` returns `1`, then it increases the value of `i` by `1`). `i` now increases with `1` and becomes `2`.

At this point, `a == 1`, `i == 2`.