# C# increment ToString

Tags: c#, tostring, increment, operator-precedence

I add an unexpected behaviour from C#/WPF

```
    private void ButtonUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int quant;
        if( int.TryParse(Qnt.Text, out quant))
        {
            string s = ((quant++).ToString());
            Qnt.Text = s;
        }
    }
```

So, if I get quant as 1, quant will be incremented to 2. But the s string will be 1. Is this a question of precedence?

EDIT:

I re-wrote this as:

```
            quant++;
            Qnt.Text = quant.ToString();
```

and now this works as I expected.

Comment: Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729

Comment: I am sorry for asking such a basic question. This is basic knowledge of C and C++

Comment: To quote from the link `Also, the way C# does it is different than how C does it` so there isn't any problem

Comment: In my C/C++ academic times I had done an uncountable number of statements like 
     printf("i: %d",i++); 

So shame on me, really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the *post*-increment operator. This evalutates to the original value, and then increments. To do what you want in a one-liner you can use the *pre*-increment operator instead.

```
(++quant).ToString();
```

But even better would be to avoid all such pitfalls and do it like this:

```
quant++;
string s = quant.ToString();
```

With the first version you have to think about the order in which things happen. In the second version no thought is required. Always value code clarity more highly than conciseness.

It's easy to believe that the one-line version is somehow faster, but that's not true. It might have been true back in the day in 1970s C systems, but even then that I doubt.

Comment: +1 because your reply is the only one that tries to explain pre/post increment and "smells" correctly :-)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're using a post-increment instead of a pre-increment... but why would you *want* to write this convoluted code? Just separate out the side-effect (incrementing) and the ToString call:

```
if (int.TryParse(Qnt.Text, out quant))
{
    quant++;
    Qnt.Text = quant.ToString();
}
```

Or even forego the actual *increment* given that you're not going to read the value again:

```
if (int.TryParse(Qnt.Text, out quant))
{
    Qnt.Text = (quant + 1).ToString();
}
```

Where possible, *avoid* using compound assignment in the middle of other expressions. It generally leads to pain.

Additionally, it feels like all this parsing and formatting is hiding the real model, which is that there should be an `int` property somewhere, which might be *reflected* in the UI. For example:

```
private void ButtonUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This is an int property
    Quantity++;
    // Now reflect the change in the UI. Ideally, do this through binding
    // instead.
    Qnt.Text = Quantity.ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1 because you are the only one that isn't fallen in the trap of trying to explain pre-post increments :-) :-)

Comment: +1 because you said the correct approach how to do it: touch the property value instead of a representation of it on the UI. As this on a WPF application, this makes even more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'll do something that shouldn't be done... I'll try to simplify what Eric Lippert wrote here [What is the difference between i++ and ++i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729) I hope I'm not writing anything too much wrong :-)

Now... What does the pre-increment and post-increment operators do? Simplifying and ignoring all the copy that are done in-between (and remembering that they **aren't atomic** operators in multi-threaded environments):

both of them are expressions (like `i + 1`) that return a result (like `i + 1`) but that have a side-effect (unlike `i + 1`). The side-effect is that they increment the variable `i`. The big question is "in which order everything happens?" The answer is quite simple:

- pre increment `++i`: increments `i` and returns the **new** value of `i`
- post increment `i++`: increments `i` and returns the **old** value of `i`

Now... The important part is that the `increments i` always happens first. Then a value (the old or the new) is returned.

Let's make an example (the example of Lippert is quite complex. I'll make a different, more simple example, that isn't as much complete but that is enough to check if the order I said before is right or not) (technically I'll make two examples)

Example 1:

```
unchecked
{
    int i = Int32.MaxValue;
    Console.WriteLine("Hello! I'm trying to do my work here {0}", i++);
    Console.WriteLine("Work done {1}", i);
}
```

Example 2:

```
checked
{
    int i = Int32.MaxValue;
    Console.WriteLine("Hello! I'm trying to do my work here {0}", i++);
    Console.WriteLine("Work done {1}", i);
}
```

`checked` means that if there is an overflow an exception (`OverflowException`) will be thrown. `unchecked` means that the same operation won't throw an exception. `Int32.MaxValue + 1` surely will overflow. With `checked` there will be an exception, with `unchecked` `i` will become -1.

Let's try running the first code piece. Result:

```
Hello! I'm trying to do my work here 2147483647
Work done -1
```

Ok... The `i` was incremented but the `Console.WriteLine` received the old value (`Int32.MaxValue == 2147483647`). From this example we can't determine the order of the post-increment and of the calling of `Console.WriteLine`.

Let's try running the second code piece. Result:

```
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

Ok... It's quite clear that first the post-increment was executed, caused an exception, and then clearly the `Console.WriteLine` wasn't executed (because the program ended).

So we know that the order I said is the right one.

Now. What should you learn from this example? The same thing I learned many years ago. Pre and post increments in C and C# are good for obfuscated code contests. They aren't good for many other things (but note that C++ is different!). From that lesson I learned that there are exactly two places where you can use post-increment freely, and there are exactly zero places where you can use pre-increment freely.

**"Safe" post-increment**

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
```

and

```
i++; // Written alone. Nothing else on the same line but a comment if necessary.
```

**"Safe" pre-increment**

```
(nothing)
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case, first `quant.ToString()` will be called and then quant will be incremented.

If you write `((++quant).ToString())` the first step will be incrementing quant and then `quant.ToString()` will be called.

Comment: False, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729 The increment is done (and is saved in the original variable) before calling the method, but the method still receives the "old" value

Comment: As it's said by Lipper, it's a common error and many books (sadly) don't point it out.

Comment: True. I was taught how things work in Java (but that shouldn't be any different, I guess) and the actual explanation was as I said in my original answer. It's probably like high school physics: what they teach you does help you understand how things work out, but not how they actually work.

Answer (score -1):

`string s = ((quant++).ToString());`

can be distributed as

use `quant` for toString() method call before incrementing, and then

execute assignment operator, and then

increment `quant'

try with ++quant.

Comment: False, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729 The increment is done (and is saved in the original variable) before calling the method, but the method still receives the "old" value