# CountDown timer in windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How can I implement a countdown timer in my Windows Phone 8.1 app? There seems to be no information available for it. All I could find works for either a Windows Forms application or a Windows Application, but none of them seems to be working on the phone app.This is what I am doing-

```
namespace Timer
{
    public partial class MainPage : Page
    {           
        DispatcherTimer mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int currentcount = 0;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            mytimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
            mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mytime_Tick);
              //HERE error comes Cannot implicitly convert type System.EventHandler to System.EventHandler<object>
        }

        private void mytime_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            timedisplayBlock.Text = currentcount++.ToString();    
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mytimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me this error-
`Cannot implicitly convert type System.EventHandler to System.EventHandler<object>`

Comment: Can you post the code you thought would work but didn't? Maybe include a screen shot of what worked in a Windows application?

Comment: use a DispatcherTimer with a timeout of 1 second

Comment: @AustinMullins I have edited my question with my code and the error.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys  I have used `DispatcherTImer` but t is giving me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Should your increment not be written as

```
timedisplayBlock.Text = (++currentcount).ToString();
```

Or

```
currentcount++;
timedisplayBlock.Text = currentcount.ToString();
```

I don't think the increment will matter too much but still should be written correctly to ensure you do not leave yourself a count behind.
- See Sergiol's issue with David's answer on the link below https://stackoverflow.com/a/7848129/2110465

The other thing i have noticed is that you are initializing the `DispatcherTimer` twice...

```
DispatcherTimer mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
...
..
mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
```

It is better practice to initialize upon the instance to save overhead, though depending on the scope of use. Given i am not aware of how the rest of your code uses it, i suggest it be rewritten as follows

```
namespace Timer
{
    public partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        DispatcherTimer mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int currentcount = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mytimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
            mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mytime_Tick);
        }

        private void mytime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timedisplayBlock.Text = (++currentcount).ToString();
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mytimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Saying all of the above, i could not reproduce the fault when replicated...

EDIT - This may be your issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16636862/2110465)

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the event handler name the event handler definition needs to be changing too, it should be:

```
mytimer.Tick += mytime_Tick; // removed the 'r'
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error-`Cannot implicitly convert type System.EventHandler to System.EventHandler<object>`

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type System.EventHandler to System.EventHandler<object>`

Comment: Yeah I already fixed that error with an extra `r`.Now it is giving me this new error which I mentioned.

Comment: I tried the same code with Windows phone silverlight,it is working but wirh windows phone blank app,it is giving the above error?What can I do to fix this?Also `using System.Windows.Threading ` is not working in `blank app`

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`private void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` 
to 
`private void mytimer_Tick(object sender, object e)`.