# C# ++ unary operator increment issue

Tags: c#, operators, increment

Question regarding the C# ++ (right placed) operator.

As the left placed ++ operator, for example, ++var, (say holding an int value of 1) will increment by 1 before any other computation takes place (example value of 1 will become 2 after expression is executed and result displayed).

Can anyone explain the difference between the left placed operator and the right placed operator? (var++) as it does not seem to increment even after the expression is executed as it is supposed to do. Here is some sample code:

```
        int var1, var2 = 5, var3 = 6;

        var1 = var2++ * --var3;
        Console.WriteLine(" {0} ", var1);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

This is just 5 x 5 due to the decrement of var3 but without the decrement it is 5 x 6 and var2++ appears to have no effect other than the value of 5 it carries. If anyone can shed light on this topic I would be grateful. Thanks.

***Issue solved. A lot of great answers and input guys, was hard trying to decide what answer to accept but you are all winners here! Thanks again for the help! =)

Comment: maybe ur confusion is because the compiler does everything in 1 shot since its in 1 statement

Comment: This is best explained here [i++ vs ++i](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/570150)

Comment: This may also be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/8573190/621334

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++x` (prefix increment) increments the value **before** the expression is evaluated. Thus it first increments the value and then returns it.

`x++` (postfix increment) increments the value **after** the expression is evaluated. Thus, it returns the unchanged value, and only after that, `x` is incremented.

After the line `var1 = var2++ * --var3;`, `var2` is actually `6`, because it was incremented **after** its value was evaluated.

So your code:

```
var1 = var2++ * --var3;
```

does something like this:

```
int oldVar2 = var2;
var2 = var2 + 1;
var3 = var3 - 1;
var1 = oldVar2 * var3;
```

Comment: A lot of great answers and input guys, was hard trying to decide what answer to accept but you are all winners here! Thanks again for the help! =)

Answer (score 5):

```
        int var1, var2 = 5, var3 = 6;

        var1 = var2++ * --var3;
        Console.WriteLine(" {0} ", var1);
        Console.WriteLine(" {0} ", var2);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

25

6

So `var2` is incremented as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In C# the **only** difference between `left-placed` operator and `right-placed` operator is the actual *returned value* after computation.

In case of `left-hand` operator, returned *new, or incremented* value.

In case of `right-hand` operator, returned value is the "old" one, even if the *real* value was incremented.

But important to know that in both cases the *sequence* of operations executed is *exactly* the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `var2` value is incremented **after** evaluation for the multiplication; the `var3` value is decremented **before** evaluation for the multiplication; it can be roughly conceptualised as:

```
    var tmp = var2; // 5
    var2 = var2 + 1; // 5 + 1 = 6
    var3 = var3 - 1; // 6 - 1 = 5;
    var1 = tmp * var3; // 5 * 5 = 25;
```

So the 25 is correct. If you inspect `var2` you will find that it has incremented as expected.

However! If a complex calculation involving `++foo` and `bar--` gets confusing, then simply *don't do it inline*; break the computation down into simpler pieces, and execute that. The compiler won't judge you.

Comment: "The var2 value is incremented after evaluation for the multiplication". This statement is incorrect even according to your sample.

Comment: @Polity no, the "evaluation for the multiplication" is where it stores the value in `tmp`. Note that it does this **before** it increments the value of `var2`. In reality, it would sit as a free value on the stack, not in a designated local, but: same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample class leveraging concept of **PreFix** and **PostFix** *increment operators*. The code is written with comments making the output more clearer.

```
public class Test
    {
            public Test()
            { }


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying Initial            i      =     " + i + "\n");   // Prints 0 i.e. Initial value of i

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying PostFix            i++    =     " + i++ + "\n"); // Prints 0. Then value of i becomes 1.

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying Post-incremented   i      =     " + i + "\n");   // Prints 1 i.e. Value of i after Post-increment

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying PreFix             ++i    =     " + ++i + "\n"); // Prints 2. Then value of i incremented to 2

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying Pre-incremented    i      =     " + i + "\n");   // Prints 2 i.e. Value of i after Pre-increment

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "---------------------------------------------" + "\n");

            int j = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying Initial            j      =     " + j + "\n");   // Prints 0 i.e. Initial value of j

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying PreFix             ++j    =     " + ++j + "\n"); // Prints 1. Then value of j incremented to 1.

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying Pre-incremented    j      =     " + j + "\n");   // Prints 1 i.e. Value of j after Pre-increment

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying PostFix            j++    =     " + j++ + "\n"); // Prints 1. Then value of j incremented to 2.

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Displaying Post-incremented   j      =     " + j + "\n");   // Prints 2 i.e. Value of j after Post-increment

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```