# Prefix operator difference in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, pre-increment

Let's have this piece of code:

```
int a = 1;
int b = ++a + ++a;
```

In C++ (VS 2010) the result is: b = 6
but in C# the result is: b = 5

What's going on there? Why are the results different?

Comment: Are there any C# experts who can say whether or not b = 5 is, in any way, standard? You can see that it's plausible: the central + is commutative; one ++a is 2 the other is 3 and you're summing them.

Comment: @Bathsheba Some interesting cross-language discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457130/pre-post-increment-operator-behavior-in-c-c-java-c-sharp

Comment: @Daniel Daranas; great link; I think this question has run its course now.

Comment: For more detailed C# discussion, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8573190/96780.

Answer (score 10):

It's `undefined behaviour` in C++. You are trying to modify value more than one time without `sequence points` (per C++98/03 standards).

About C++11

> The value computations of the operands of an
> operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. If a side effect on a scalar
> object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
> using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> i = v[i++]; // the behavior is undefined
> i = i++ + 1; // the behavior is undefined
> ```

Answer (score 7):

In C++, `int b = ++a + ++a` is undefined behaviour so you can expect *any* result.

Comment: The last time I tried it, it drank all the beer in my fridge!

Comment: @MatthewWatson I added that possible outcome to my answer, for completeness. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

C# and C++ are different languages, with different semantics.

C# decides to first execute first one ++a, then the other ++a and finally the addition of these two expressions, hence the result is 5.

In C++ you have undefined behaviour. The result could be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 34500 or any other. Another possible outcome is [Matthew Watson drinking all the beer in his fridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165292/prefix-operator-difference-in-c-and-c-sharp/17165438#comment24851103_17165333). Anything can happen, actually.

It doesn't make sense, in general, to expect the same behaviour from two different languages. Each one follows its own rules.

---

**Note:** See this question [Pre & post increment operator behavior in C, C++, Java, & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6457130/96780) for further cross-language discussion.

Comment: Dude, the C# result is 5, not 6.

Comment: And +1 for bringing C# into the answer. But is the C# version guaranteed for all future versions of C#?

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm too lazy to look it up, but I guess the sequential order of evaluation between the two ++a is well defined. One last thing: in any case, I despise such coding style.

Comment: I find prefix/postfix operators so low-level that I naturaly expected their behaviour to be the same across all languages. But apparently it's not the case.