# How to update the accessed node value it in the XML

Tags: c#, xml

Here I am trying to read the TID Value and I am able to read the Value(Intially it is 1)..and every time I need to increment by one and update to TID node value

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

    xml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFile1.xml"));

    XmlNode node = xml.SelectSingleNode("AllID/ID/TID");

    int s = Convert.ToInt32( node.InnerText);

    node.InnerText= s++.ToString();

    xml.Save(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFile1.xml"));

}
```

But here it is not updating the TID value

```
<AllID>
 <ID>
<TID>1</TID>
</ID>
</AllID>
```

Comment: Checked with small sample,, Value is updating.. Please see sample xml with your code : <xml>
  <h1>OldValue</h1>
</xml> Select H1 node -> xml/h1.. Instead node.Value = s++.ToString();-> chnage to node.InnerText= s++.ToString();

Comment: Please see below answer

Comment: This is really duplicate of [pre vs. post increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573190/c-sharp-pre-post-increment-confusions) but since this question have nothing actually pointing to that in text I don't want to close it as duplicate..

Comment: Note that none of the answers actually highlight the real problem so far...

Answer (score 1):

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

```
xml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFile1.xml"));

XmlNode node = xml.SelectSingleNode("AllID/ID/TID");

int s = Convert.ToInt32( node.InnerText);

 node.InnerText = (++s).ToString(); //Increment and make string

xml.Save(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFile1.xml"));
```

Comment: node.InnerText = (++s).ToString(); //Increment and make string Instead S++.ToString()..

Answer (score 0):

What about `node.InnerText = s++.ToString();`? I haven't tested it.

Comment: I added node.InnerText only but it is not updating