# Addition with preincrement losing 1

Tags: c#, operators, pre-increment

Why does TestAddition result in 12 instead o 13? It should be 5 + 1 + 7 = 13, but assert fails with

> Expected: 13
>
> But was:  12

```
int method(int a)
{
    return 7;
}

[Test]
public void TestAddition()
{
    int row = 5;
    row += method(++row);

    Assert.AreEqual(13, row, "Why is it twelve instead of 13?");
}
```

Comment: [C# Pre- & Post Increment confusions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573190/c-sharp-pre-post-increment-confusions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your

```
row += method(++row);
```

equals to

```
row = row + method(++row);
```

Since [`+` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx) is [left associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), it calculates first `row` as a `5` and `method` always return `7` *no matter* which parameter it takes.

```
row = row + method(++row);
       ^          ^
       5          7
```

That's why result will be `12`.

Answer (score 1):

```
row += method(++row);
```

is the same as

```
row = row + method(++row);
```

The operands are evaluated from left to right, so the value of the left operand (`row`) is evaluated before `row` is incremented in `method(++row)`.

The expected result is 12.