# ArgumentOutOfRangeException List error c#

Tags: c#

Can someone please explain why this line does not work

```
dest = await GetDestinationContext(pbx.Nodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == dests[normalTsCount++]));
```

But this does

```
dest = await GetDestinationContext(pbx.Nodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == dests[normalTsCount]));
normalTsCount++;
```

The first line gives an ArgumentOutOfRangeException the first time it runs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pre- & Post Increment in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573190/pre-post-increment-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @mamen the problem here has nothing to do with pre/post incrementation, it has to do with an incrementation being called multiple times because it is wrapped in a callback

Comment: @sschwei1 You are right, my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because at

```
dest = await GetDestinationContext(pbx.Nodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == dests[normalTsCount++]))
```

the `normalTsCount++` incerements each iteration over `Nodes`