# result of this expression is not what i learned

Tags: c#, expression, operator-precedence, associativity

In below code, result is -6. why?

```
`    int x = 5;
    int y = 3;
    int result = x++ - (--y + ++x) - y--;`
```

I think at first, inside parenthesis evaluated, then outside of it in left to right order, but in this way, the result will not be -6.
this is order in my opinion:

1. ++x
2. --y
3. x++
4. y--
5. first - from left
6. - in middle of expression
7. last - from left

in number 1 value is 6 and x is 6

in number 2 value is 2 and y is  2

in number 3 value is 6 and x is 7

in number 4 value is 2 and y is 1

in number 5,6,7 expression is 6 - 8 - 2 = -4 which is not  equal -6;

in terms of operator precedence and Operator associativity

Comment: "I think at first, inside parenthesis evaluated" why do you think that? And why is 1 and 2 seemingly swapped?

Comment: Duplicate of [Pre- & Post Increment in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573190/pre-post-increment-in-c-sharp)

Comment: parenthesis have higher order than every operator.  1 and 2 is inside parenthesis and is pre increment/decrement so the order of evaluation is right to left.

Comment: Here are the rules explained succinctly: https://ericlippert.com/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/

Comment: `x++ - (--y + ++x) - y--` for your inputted `x = 5` and `y = 3` will evaluate as `5 - (2 + 7) - 2`. Parenthesis doesn't prioritize "**in which order do `++` or `--`**", they prioritize "**in which order calculate results**". So order looks like "**get all resulting values first by `++`/`--`, then calculate values in parenthesis, then subtract it from first value at left, then subract right value**". Not "**get resulting values in parentesis and calculate them, then calculate left value and subtract result of parenthesis part from it, then calculate right value and subtract it**".

Comment: That just means that when going from left to right, if you encounter a parens you calculate that as a whole. Not that you should calculate all paren before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the C# specification ([ECMA-334, 6th edition, June 2022](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/), §11.4.1):

> Operands in an expression are evaluated from left to right.

This means that your initial assumption is not correct: "I think at first, inside parenthesis evaluated".

---

In this case `x++` will be evaluated first; the sequence would look something like this:

1. `x++` is evaluated, returning 5, but saving 6 in x
2. `--y` is evaluated, returning 2, and saving 2 in y
3. `++x` is evaluated, returning 7 (because `x` was 6 from the previous operation)
4. stuff in the parentheses is evaluated (2 + 7) = 9
5. first subtraction gets evaluated: `5` (from step 1.) `-` `9` (from step 4.) = `-4`
6. `y--` gets evaluated, returning 2, but saving 1 in y
7. final subtraction gets evaluated: `-4` (from step 5.) `-` `2` (from step 6.) = `-6`

As mentioned in one of the comments ([Precedence vs associativity vs order](https://ericlippert.com/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/)), it's important to differentiate between:

- > **Precedence** rules describe how an underparenthesized expression should be parenthesized when the expression mixes different kinds of operators
- > **Associativity** rules describe how an underparenthesized expression should be parenthesized when the expression has a bunch of the same kind of operator
- > **Order of evaluation** rules describe the order in which each operand in an expression is evaluated

Comment: Thanks for you reply. So What is Associativity Left to right OR right to left? for example I heard post Increment/Decrement is Right to left but pre Increment/decrement is left to right. where this rule will apply? If this is true , ++x should evaluate before --y.

Comment: From the specification: _When an operand occurs between two operators with the same precedence, the associativity of the operators controls the order in which the operations are performed._ ++x and --y are both unary operations. We can still talk about their associativity but it can get confusing. --x and ++x are left associative, meaning you will first "evaluate" `--` and then `x`. Right associative for x++ means that you will first "evaluate" `++` and then `x`

Comment: For the example you gave, `If this is true , ++x should evaluate before --y`, no because operator between these two operands is a `+`, and `+` is left associative (_Except for the assignment operators and the null coalescing operator, all binary operators are left associative, meaning that operations are performed from left to right._)

Answer (score 0):

```cs
int result = x++ - (--y + ++x) - y--;
```

[Generates IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTd2AHbAEAHgQC8BAKwBuLt2p8BAT1EE807LJryCAJwCmAZwCuEAWMHx4BALQEWVq0ssXBHGwvtruAXxxegA===) that is roughly equivalent to;

```cs
var t0 = x;
var t1 = t0 + 1;
x = t1;

var t2 = y;
var t3 = t2 - 1;
y = t3;

var t4 = x;
var t5 = t4 + 1;
x = t5;

var t6 = t3 + t5;
var t7 = t0 - t6;

var t8 = y;
var t9 = t8 - 1;
y = t9;

var t10 = t7 - t8;
int result = t10;
```

The values you have supplied are evaluated left to right. The binary operations are evaluated when both the left hand and right hand values are available. The parenthesis enforce which values are bound to the left hand and right hand of each binary operation.