# Why does this snippet display the answer as 6?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

A classmate of mine asked this question, and I wanted to be sure that I was telling him the correct answer.  Essentially the code below (which does indeed display "6" as the answer) confused him when it got to MessageBox.Show((i--).ToString());.

My explanation was that the decrement operation (i--) isn't actually taking place, since it is being passed to the .Show method of the MessageBox object.  So it displays 6 because it's not actually reducing that value by 1.

Is this the correct explanation?  I've never tried to throw inc/dec operations while also displaying values at the same time, so I'm not sure if my reasoning on this is correct.  Thanks!

```
        int i = 6;            // I starts as 6...
        if (i >=4 )           // Then the check to see if i >= 4 is TRUE...
        {
            if( i == 5)       // The check to see if i == 5 is FALSE...
            {
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()); 
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show((i--).ToString());  // ****
            }
        }
        else 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show((i++).ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`i--` returns the value of i and returns the value before the decrement.

You should read it logically in the lexical order (as was intended by the creators) :

```
puts the value
and then decrements
```

If it's 6 before, it returns 6 (which is printed) even if just after the value of i is 5.

Note that `--i` decrements and returns the decremented value.

Comment: "returns the value of i and then decrements." this is wrong. The sequence of operations in both cases are **exactly** the same. The difference is which value actually *returned* (incremented or not)

Comment: @Tigran It depends of what you mean by returning. This comment doesn't help make the problem clear as I was trying to give the logical meaning of the operator ^^

Comment: @dystroy: look on [Eric Lippert answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: As for every operation, it's important, when you go deeper, to know how it's implemented (at least know that it's not atomic and not "thread-safe"). But this kind of deep detail is interesting when you're talking about the details of the operator, not when analyzing the upper level algorithm. I agree your link is very interesting. It's just off topic.

Comment: @Tigran that link was extremely useful and interesting.  I didn't realize things went that deep...very cool!  Thank you, everyone, for answering the question!

Answer (score 4):

`i--` returns the pre-decrement value.  If you want the value *after* decrementing, you want `--i`

Answer (score 2):

`i--` means decrement i after using it.

Answer (score 1):

This (variable--) is a *postfix* decrement operation.

[From msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx):

> The result of the operation is the value of the operand "before" it
>   has been decremented.

So ToString() is applied on the present value(6) of '*i*', then the it's value is decremented.

Also see C# spec. in msdn: [Postfix increment and decrement operators](http://Postfix%20increment%20and%20decrement%20operators)