# Dynamically created button creation, Loop not creating unique ID's

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on creating buttons that are created dynamically based the results of a SQL Query:

```
private void createPagingButtons(DateTime firstDayofWeek, DateTime lastDayofWeek)
{
    int i = 1;
    SqlDataReader returnedQuery = getDefaultUser(firstDayofWeek, lastDayofWeek);
    while (returnedQuery.Read())
    {
        string buttonName = returnedQuery["Person"].ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(buttonName);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = i.ToString();
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btn.Text = buttonName;
        pagingPanel.Controls.Add(btn);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The way I am trying to assign unique button ID's is by assigning them a number that is incremented each time the while loop iterates:

```
btn.ID = i.ToString();
```

But it's not working and I am getting an error: 
Multiple controls with the same ID '1' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

WHy is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use meaningful names like `BtnPerson_1`?

Comment: What happens if you add letters `btn.ID = "btn_" + i.ToString();` ?

Comment: btn.ID = "Btn_" + i.ToString(); causes the same error. Multiple controls with the same ID 'Btn_1' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: Is it possible that your getDefaultUser method is actually only returning one row, and that it's the createPagingButtons method that is being called multiple times to create multiple buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this could occur is if this method were executed more than one time **or** if these buttons are somehow persisted during the load and then you call it again. However, dynamic controls are for all intents and purposes **not** persisted and must be recreated on each post back to be useful.

Thus my conclusion, you're calling it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

As other users said, this error will be thrown if the function is called more than once. Your function will re-start at one each time it is called. Which will duplicate the IDs.

*Assuming* this is actually the desired behavior, that your function can be called multiple times and will create new buttons each time. Making your `int i = 1;` a class level variable would resolve this.

Answer (score -2):

Replace i++ with ++i.. This should solve your issue..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i