# C# in a nutshell example misunderstanding ++ unary operator increment

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I am reading C# 5.0 in a nutshell and I have the following statements:

```
int x = 0;

while (true)
{
    if (x++ > 5)
        break ;      // break from the loop
}
x.Dump();
```

Executing the statements on LINQPad 4 the output is **7**.

I still don't understand WHY?. Why it is not 6 being the condition: x++>5

Comment: Take a look at what x++ does with x, x++ is not the same as ++x. If it was ++x instead of x++ it would break with x = 6.

Comment: Hit me if I'm wrong but I think its the pre-expression. The ++ is evaluated after the `> 5`.

Comment: i would recommand not to write code like this - it's bad partice in my opinion. just write it clear and easy `if(x >= 7)`

Comment: This is not my code. This is an example of the book: C# 5.0 in a nutshell. Please at least read the first sentence of the question

Comment: it was just a suggestion not an answer or any kind of offence

Comment: For more information about postfix increment, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/1336590

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `++` operator increments the value and returns the *original value*.

So when `x` was 5, `x` was incremented and the condition `5 > 5` is evaluated.

Then, when `x` was 6, `x` was incremented and the condition `6 > 5` is evaluated, which results in the `break`. Because `x` was still incremented, the value of `x` in the end is 7.

People often say that when the `++` operator is use as a postfix, the increment is executed after the comparison, but this is not technically true, which is shown by decompilation in LinqPad:

```
int x = 5;
if (x++ > 5) 
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0004:  dup         
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0006:  add         // <---- Increment
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // x <-- Result of increment is popped from the stack and stored in a variable
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0009:  cgt         // <---- Comparison
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000C:  ceq         
IL_000E:  stloc.1     // CS$4$0000
IL_000F:  ldloc.1     // CS$4$0000
IL_0010:  brtrue.s    IL_0019
IL_0012:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0013:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

Comment: I am trying to find some documentation about the loop for and the original value returned after the increment. Could you show me some link? I can not find it

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx

Answer (score 5):

`x++ > 5` means check the value of `x` against `5` *then* increment it. Which means your `break` is not reached until `x == 7`.

The result would be 6 if you used `++x`, i.e. increment x *and then* test it against 5.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks. Never had to used before de x++

Comment: Although effectively the same, and often explained this way, this is not entirely accurate. The increment is executed *before* the comparison, but the return value of the increment operation is the *original value*, before incrementing.

Comment: @Rik Technically correct (the best kind of correct!), but in terms of understanding the statement, this makes it a lot easier

Comment: I appreciate the Futurama reference, but I do think it's important to be accurate with this sort of thing. If you're aiming for an easy explanation, you should be clear that it's a simplification. Use language like "You can think of it as if (...)" instead of "This is how it works" when it really doesn't.

Comment: I think that's a fair point.

Answer (score 4):

The following are the iterations of the loop:

- `x == 0` -> comparison returns `false` -> `x` increased to `1`
- `x == 1` -> comparison returns `false` -> `x` increased to `2`
- `x == 2` -> comparison returns `false` -> `x` increased to `3`
- `x == 3` -> comparison returns `false` -> `x` increased to `4`
- `x == 4` -> comparison returns `false` -> `x` increased to `5`
- `x == 5` -> comparison returns `false` -> `x` increased to `6`
- `x == 6` -> comparison returns `true` -> `x` increased to `7` -> `if`-block is entered and the loop is left

The last value of `x`, namely `7`, will be output.

Note that the `x++` operation modifies the value of `x`, *after* the comparison `x > 5` is evaluated, but *regardless* of whether or not the comparison returns `true` and the `if`-block is entered.

Answer (score 4):

On C#, the ++ unary operator, when wrote after its operand (it can be either ++x or x++) executes itself **after** evaluations in the expression. That means:

- When x is 5, the expression is gonna be evaluated as false (5 is not > than 5) and then increment it to 6.
- Then, when x is 6, the expression is gonna be evaluated as true yes (6 is > than 5), but **then** it is gonna increment again, breaking when x is **7**.

Comment: Although effectively the same, and often explained this way, this is not entirely accurate. The increment is executed before the comparison, but the return value of the increment operation is the original value, before incrementing.

Comment: @Rik, you're right! :)  The only thing that **really** changes is the return value of the operation.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `x++` will evaluate after the check. So when it finally gets to `x == 6` the condition will be met (`6 > 5`) and then **afterwards** it will be incremented (to `7`)

It is easier to explain with some alternate code, which will produce the same result:

```
while (true)
{
    if(x > 5)
    {
        //x = 6
        x++;
        //x = 7
        break;
    }
    x++;//x increments from 0 - 6, over 6 loops
}
```

Comment: Although effectively the same, and often explained this way, this is not entirely accurate. The increment is executed before the comparison, but the return value of the increment operation is the original value, before incrementing.

Comment: @Rik... Yes, I seen your comment coming ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You're evaluating x before you increment it, so your condition of 6 will cause the break and then it goes up 1 to 7.  I think you're expecting this:

```
int x = 0;

while (true)
{
    if (++x > 5)
        break ;      // break from the loop
}
x.Dump();
```

This will increment x before you evaluate its condition.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the `++`

The `++` operator counts x one up everytime it hits the line.
And as you have a `while(true)` loop it will count x one up in the if statement everytime it reaches that if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's 7 because even when it does the check for 6 > 5, it increments by one. Because of the unary operator `x++`.

Answer (score 0):

x++ increments x after the value has been read. This means that when it increments once after the comparison fails.
++x on the other hand increments before the value is read.

Comment: This answer is nonsensical; how can a variable be *incremented* before it is *read*?  Here, I have a variable x. I'd like you to assign x+1 to that variable, but you're not allowed to read the value of x before you do. How would you do that?

Comment: Semantically it makes fine sense to me. The value will not be grammatically read-evaluated before it has been incremented. In machine code, which the code will essentially become, it may indeed be possible to increment a memory location without loading it into a register.