# Decrement operator

Tags: javascript, decrement

#### I was having trouble with a piece of code and found out that the problem was that decrement (--) was not doing anything.  Instead I am using -1, but what is it that it doesn't funciton?

#### _01 is simply a number

```
 minOne = document.getElementById("ctdwnTimeDispSec").value=_01--;
```

#### This is what works now

```
 minOne = document.getElementById("ctdwnTimeDispSec").value=_01-1;
```

Comment: What do you think `_01--` does? Because it doesn't do that... See also: [What is the difference between i++ and ++i?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/7586) - It's about C#, but you should read it anyway.

Comment: Yes +01 is a variable

Comment: `_01--` means `_01 = _01 - 1` See the difference?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek has a point, try --_01 instead or _01-=1.

Comment: @user3280654 Your answer lies in 1st comment.. that is to use pre decrement operator --_01 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You should use `--_01`

`_01--` will do `-1` after the expression.

Comment: You are assuming User3280654 *wants* to change the value of variable `_01`. If `value=_01-1` "works now", that probably isn't true...

Answer (score 1):

The -- operator will decrement the number it's operated on, during or after the statement, based on whether it is placed before or after the number.

e.g. Placing -- after `a`, will modify the value of `a`, on the following line.

```
var a=5
var b=a--
```

afterwards, will equal:

```
a=4
b=5
```

e.g. Placing -- before `a`, will modify `a` on the same line.

```
var a=5
var b=--a
```

afterwards, will equal:

```
a=4
b=4
```

When you use `var b=a-1`, the javascript will execute the `a-1` on that line, making `b=4`, and not changing `a`. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the pre decrrement operator instead of post decrement operator, other you can get the decremented value after that expression.