# What's the difference between i-- and --i in c#

Tags: c#

How does "i--" differ from "--i" in c#?  is this the same?  it seems to equate to the same thing.

```
i--;
```

other answers seem to say i++ or ++i, but i am asking about i-- or --i

Comment: google `predecrement` and `postdecrement` operators. https://www.google.com/webhp?q=pre%20decrement%20and%20post%20decrement%20in%20c%23

Comment: i don't have google i have bing i think

Comment: @YourMomma then google it with bing!

Comment: wouldn't that be binging it?

Comment: @YourMomma Google can be a generic term in common discussions. It means "go use a search engine". It doesn't have to mean use google.com. Bing will work just fine.

Comment: i now see @alexfreiria's answer i can click on it!

Comment: For the _technically_ correct answer see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/1081897).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

--i decrements the variable i BEFORE an operation, i-- after.  makes a big difference in, for example,

```
int i=5;
Console.WriteLine(--i);

i=5;
Console.WriteLine(i--);
```

Comment: Your example produces the exact same output whether you use `i++` or `++i` in the loop.

Comment: oh ok, isee the output difference now thanks