# Operator overloading ++ on C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Let's say i have a class named `A`, and i don't have the class implementation.
Which will be more expensive on run time scale:
The postfix or the prefix ++ operation?

Example:

```
void some_function{
    ...
    A x;

    ++x;

    x++;

    ...
}
```

I read online that the suffix `x++` operator on classes will do 2 constructor calls, but no explanation was given.
I can't find a decent explanation for it. why is it we have 2 calls and none on the other?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/increment-pre-post-speed.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between i++ and ++i?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: @Satus, It's not a duplicate, it's a different question. i do know the suffix and prefix differences.

Comment: You cannot know if you don't know the implementation.

Comment: Prefix: increment x, then return me x. Postfix: create temp variable (that is a copy of x), then increment x, then return me that temp variable. But in C++ you can overload both operators the way you want to. So if you don't know the implementation, you don't know the result of calling `++x` or `x++`.

Comment: @Satus, The creation of temp is, in fact, another constructor call. am i wrong? this means since A is not a basic type like int or long, we will always call another constructor, hence, more expansive to execute?

Comment: @Itzik984 Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible answers to this question, because of the fact you don't know the class's implementation (as you say).

## Scenario one: The class is reasonable

In this scenario, the semantics of `++` are similar to those of built-in types and standard library iterators: `++x` is preincrement, `x++` is postincrement.

In such case, `++x` returns the value of `x` after the increment. It's actually expected of `++x` to return `x` by reference, making `++ ++ x` legal. A typical implementation would be:

```
A& A::operator++()
{
  increment_somehow();
  return *this;
}
```

As you see, no copying (construction) is necessary.

`x++`, on the other hand, returns the value *before* the increment. Which means it must store the value somewhere to be able to return it. A typical implementation would be:

```
A A::operator++(int)
{
  A old(*this); // copy construction
  ++(*this); // re-use preincrement to keep semantics consistent
  return old;  // move construction of return value (possibly elided)
}
```

As my comments above show, there are two constructor calls involved (even though one of them can be elided).

## Scenario two: The class is arbitrary

If the prefix and postfix `++` are not indended to match standard semantics, then naturally all bets are off, as the functions can do literally anything. Without knowing more about them, they cannot be compared.