# Trying to understand how ConcurrentDictionary works

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, concurrentdictionary

I would like to initialize value to 0 if it does not already exists. Otherwise it should increment existing value.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
dic.AddOrUpdate(1, 0, (key, old) => old++);
dic.AddOrUpdate(2, 0, (key, old) => old++);
```

At this point, dictionary has keys of 1 and 2 with value of 0 each.

```
        dic.AddOrUpdate(1, 0, (key, old) => old++);
```

At this point for the key 1 the value should be 1 whereas for key 2 it should be 0, however, both have value of 0. Any idea why?

Comment: sorry my mistake. Updated question

Comment: Refer eric lippert answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i and definitely not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a misconception:

> ```
> dic.AddOrUpdate(1, 0, (key, old) => old++);
> ```
>
> At this point for the key 1 the value should be 1

when you use `old++` it returns the original value before the modification to be stored. It is as if you did the equivalent of:

```
dic.AddOrUpdate(1, 0, (key, old) => 
{
    var original = old;
    old = old + 1;
    return original;
});
```

You want `++old` which will return the modified value or just use

```
dic.AddOrUpdate(1, 0, (key, old) => old + 1);
```

Comment: Or just `old + 1` for clarity.

Comment: sorry had mistakes in my question. Fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
dic.AddOrUpdate(1, 0, (key, old) => old + 1);
```

I think that's because old is a parameter of the Func<>, it cant be modified.

Comment: It's not that old cannot be modified it's that `old++` returns the value before the increment when you want the value after.  So `++old` would also work.

Comment: You can modify `old`, it's just that it doesn't *accomplish* anything.  The value will be set to whatever the lambda returns, not what the value of `old` is at the end of the method.