# a++ didn't increment in C# program

Tags: c#

I have been trying to understand the difference between `ref`
 and `out` in C# and faced this misunderstanding of `a++` and `++a`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main ( string [] args )
    {
        int a = 3;
        incr (  a ) ;
        Console.ReadKey ();

    }


    public static void incr (   int a ) // a = 3
    {
        Console.WriteLine (++a); // a incremented to 4
        Console.WriteLine ( a++ ); // a should be incremented to 5 , but it is still 4
    }
}
```

can anyone explain why `a++` didn't increment to 5 in the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void incr (int a ) // a = 3
{
    Console.WriteLine (++a); // Pre-Increment:  Increment to 4 and pass it in.
    Console.WriteLine (a++); // Post-Increment: Increment to 5, but use the old value (4).
    Console.WriteLine (a);   // Will show 5
}
```

The problem is that `a++` will increment to 5, but it will use the old value for the parameter before it was incremented. `++a` increments and the new value will be passed into the method.

Comment: can you check your code , I think you mean the  first `++a` should be `a++` right ?

Comment: check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i) @HassanNahhal

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary thanks a lot, i checked all the questions and there was a guy called  saying that the answers are wrong with high reputation, i read his answer but it was so hard to understand.

Comment: @HassanNahhal I see what you are getting at. He is correct and I will reword. Technically it does increment, but uses the old value.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on the [++ operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx)

> The first form is a prefix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand after it has been incremented.
>   The second form is a postfix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand before it has been incremented.

So your code expanded out looks more like this

```
public static void incr (   int a ) // a = 3
{
    int aResult;

    //++a
    a = a + 1; // a = 4
    aResult = a; //aResult = 4
    Console.WriteLine (aResult ); //  prints 4

    //a++
    aResult = a; //aResult = 4
    a = a + 1; //a = 5
    Console.WriteLine (aResult); // prints 4 because the result was copied before the increment.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a++ is evaluated then assigned. But ++a is Assigned then evaluated.

```
i = a++;
// a = a + 1;
// i = a
```

but

```
i = ++a;
// i = a
// a = a + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pre and post increment.

`++p` -- pre-increment will increment first and then will display in console output

whereas `p++` will display in console first and then will increment and so you the result.

So, in your case

```
Console.WriteLine (++a); // a incremented to 4
Console.WriteLine ( a++ ); // it will display 4
Console.WriteLine ( a ); // it will be 5 this time
```