# What is the difference between n-- and --n

Tags: javascript

Given this piece of code :

```
var n = 1;
console.log(n);
console.log(n--);
console.log(n);
```

The output is

> 1
>
> 1
>
> 0

And for this one

```
var n = 1;
console.log(n);
console.log(--n);
console.log(n);
```

The output is

> 1
>
> 0
>
> 0

What is happening?

Comment: If you want it to be done before, use `--n` instead.

Comment: `n--` is not `--n` - and both variants work identically in javascript as they do in C/C++/C# and all the other spinoffs and variations

Comment: I thought the usual behavior of `n--` was to decrement `n` as the last operation on the line. Maybe you're thinking of `--n` which decrements right away.

Comment: @JaromandaX Strictly speaking, [C# does it differently to C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/50447)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the value to update immediately you can move the `--` to the front of the variable name:

```
var n = 1;
console.log(n);
console.log(--n);
console.log(n);
```

> 1
>
> 0
>
> 0

This is also [how it works in C](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-decrement-operator/).

> The decrement operator decrements (subtracts one from) its operand and returns a value.
>
> - If used postfix (for example, x--), then it returns the value before decrementing.
> - If used prefix (for example, --x), then it returns the value after decrementing.
>
> — [MDN's notes on Arithmetic Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement)

Comment: OP is asking if why this behavior is different from languages like `C`. If his assumption is wrong please mention it in your answer

Answer (score 4):

First it's not only javascript who does this. All other programming languages including C, C++, PHP etc does the same. Check the following code:

```
var i = 1;
console.log(i) // Prints 1
console.log(i--) // It first prints the variable i then decrements it by 1. Therefore the result would be 1.
i = 1;
console.log(--i) // It FIRST decrements the variable i by 1 then prints its decremented value which prints the number 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of increment / dectement operators: prefix and postfix.
Increment prefix adds 1 immediately, before the operand will be used in current code string operation. So `n=++x` will first increment `x` and then puts the incremented x to the `n`
Increment postfix adds 1 after the value of the operand was used in current code string operation. So `n = x++` will first puts x to n and then x will be incremented

Decrement operator acts identically