# Post-increment within a self-assignment, different results between VS2013 and GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2013, post-increment, pre-increment

The codes in this [Post-increment within a self-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783989/post-increment-within-a-self-assignment), testing with C++.

However I get different result between `VS2013` and `GCC4.8.4`

```
int cc = 42;
cc = cc++;
cout << cc << endl;
```

The result of `VS2013` is `43`, but the result of `GCC` is `42`. It confuse me...

Which result is correct?

Comment: Both of them are correct because this should be undefined behavior and anything may happen.

Answer (score 2):

[This is textbook undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point#Examples_of_ambiguity). The compiler can do whatever the hell it wants to. By the language spec, it is allowed to halt and catch fire, should it so choose; be glad they just did something vaguely related to the nonsense you fed them.