# Start Game from the Last Scene Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After closing the game and reopening it, I want to load the last scene, so the player can continue from the level he reached. I've tried using PlayerPrefs as you see in the code bellow, but the game crash on startup.

**GameManager Script:**

```
    bool GameHasEnded = false;
    public float RestartDelay = 2f;
    public float NextLevelDelay = 5f;

    int level_index;

    private void Start()
    {

        level_index = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Last_Level");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(level_index);


    }

    public void CompleteLevel()
    {
        Invoke("NextLevel", NextLevelDelay);
        level_index = level_index++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Last_Level", level_index);
    }

    public void EndGame()
    {
        if (GameHasEnded == false)
        {
            GameHasEnded = true;
            Invoke("Restart", RestartDelay);
        }
    }

    void NextLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex +1);
    }

    void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().path);
    }
}
```

All scenes are linked with `GameManager`, they all have the same code that load the next scene:

```
FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().CompleteLevel();
```

Comment: Does it print any errors to the log when it crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a `defaultValue` for `GetInt` so that the first time it starts up, it can pick the appropriate scene to start at.

Also, you need to track whether or not you have already loaded at scene start, and only do this load if it hasn't yet happened. `GameManager` seems like it should be made into a **singleton** but since it's not, you can just make this `loaded` flag static, so that is common among all `GameManager` instances.

Altogether, this might look like this:

```
public readonly int defaultLastLevel = 1; // Set as appropriate
private static bool loaded = false;

void Start()
{
    if (!loaded) {
        loaded = true;
        level_index = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Last_Level", defaultLastLevel);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(level_index);
    }
}
```

Also, your `CompleteLevel` has some very strange code where you post-increment and assign in the same line:

```
level_index = level_index++;
```

This is extremely hard to read and actually [doesn't do what you want it to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783989/post-increment-within-a-self-assignment). You can do `level_index = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1;` instead.

Also, you need to `Save` changes you make to `PlayerPrefs` with `PlayerPrefs.Save();`

Altogether, this makes your CompleteLevel look like this:

```
public void CompleteLevel()
{
    Invoke("NextLevel", NextLevelDelay);
    level_index = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1; // use this instead
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Last_Level", level_index);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, the game start but nothing was working

Comment: @Taik Please be more descriptive than "nothing was working." Did the wrong scene load? Did it reformat your hard drive? There is no way for us to know.

Comment: The first scene was loaded but it's paused, so I can't play or do anything

Comment: @Taik That sounds like a completely separate problem now. Did your code work with `LoadScene` **before** you tried using `PlayerPrefs`?

Comment: It was working perfectly when there was nothing on the Start method

Comment: @Taik It seems like you have one instance of `GameManagement` in each scene, so you need to make sure it doesn't re-try to load the scene perpetually. I added a `loaded` flag to my answer that should prevent this.

Comment: Now the game work fine but after closing and reopening, the last scene didn't load, it start from the first scene again

Comment: @Taik I found a bug in your `CompleteLevel` method. Check my answer for a fix.

Comment: It work only with the second scene, I mean for example when closing after reaching the scene 5, on the next start the scene 2 was loaded instead of scene 5.

Comment: @Taik There is not enough information to determine why. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53990274/edit) or [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include the code that detects when scene 4 is complete and calls the code that transitions to scene 5.

Comment: All scenes are linked with GameManager Script (this one), they all have the same code that load the next scene ( I mean this code: FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().CompleteLevel();)

Comment: @Taik In that case it sounds like you never call `PlayerPrefs.Save();`, so depending on how you quit your application, it may never save. I have added that to my answer in `CompleteLevel`.  If that does not fix the problem, can you add a breakpoint on the `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` line and share the value of `level_index` each time the breakpoint is hit?

Comment: that didn't work, sorry but I don't know how to do breakpoint

Comment: In that case, add a `Debug.Log("level_index: " + level_index);` before the `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` line and tell me what it prints out each time it logs.

Comment: when moving from scene to the next one I got the same message: "level_index: 1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GameManager:NextLevel() (at Assets/Script/GameManager.cs:45)"

Comment: I found the solution, it's a little a bit different, I used "level_index = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Last_Level");" instead of "level_index = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Last_Level", defaultLastLevel);", and "level_index = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1;" instead of "level_index += 1;"

Comment: @Taik you still need to use `defaultLastLevel` or it won't work for someone who has never played before. I put the second part in my answer.