# Why does this code return 0 indefinitely?

Tags: c#

This is a simplified version of something that came up in my code and I couldn't explain.

The code keeps writing 0 in the console output and never ends.

```
int test = 0;
while (test < 100)
{
    test = test % 2 == 0 ? test++ : test + 2;
    Console.WriteLine(test);
}
```

I understand that it's not necessary to assign anything to your variable when you use the ++ operator but I don't see how it would change the outcome either.

In my mind what should happen in the first loop is the following:
The condition is met and test++ is executed but only after assigning its original value to test, since it's test++ and not ++test.
So test is assigned a 0 and afterwards its value is incremented to 1.

But that's not what happens, it just stays 0 so what is actually happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test++` is not the same as `test + 1`.  It returns the value of `test` from *before* the assignment while also *assigning a new value to the variable* at that point in time that is one more than the current value.  Thus `test = test++` adds one to test via the `test++` and then assigns it back to the original value through the explicit assignment.

Since you're assigning `test` *explicitly*, you should just use `test + 1` to return the value of test plus one without mutating it.

Comment: You haven't really answered the question here. He/She knows that first it gets the value before the assignment. However, after that we are "assigning a new value" to that same variable so why does it not increment?

Comment: @JoeStarbright It *does* increment, as I said in the answer.  It increments the value, and then assigns a new value to it, with the new value being the value of the variable before the increment.

Comment: @JoeStarbright You should create your own answer.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I did (like the others), but then deleted it as I dont think its fully explained

Comment: @JoeStarbright What about it do you think is not explained?

Comment: We can simplify it to `test = test++;` which is the equivalent of `var temp = test; test = test + 1; test = temp;` which hopefully makes it more obvious why the value is ultimately unchanged.

Comment: @Servy so are you saying these are the steps of the compiler in this order (when doing test++)
1. Take test and increment the value now.
2. Return the test value as it was before the increment

Comment: @JoeStarbright Yes, that's what the `++` postfix operator does.  The prefix operator returns the value after the increment, rather than before.

Comment: All this discussion had already happened in the past ... so save your time :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/33784071/477420. TL;DR: = has lower priority than ++ and hence all ++ finishes before =.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. Not familiar yet with the whole SO off hand : )