# Getting the next item in the List<string> based on current item

Tags: c#, string, list, indexing

I have a `List<string>`, which contains payrollnumbers as strings, e.g.:

```
 List<string> payrollnumbers = new List<string>() { "0","1","3" };
```

I want to get the next value in the list, so:

- if `currpayrollnumber` is 0, I want to get the value 1,
- if `currpayrollnumber` is 1, I want to get the value 3,
- etc.

I have the following code, however it does not work like expected:

```
 List<string> payrollnumbers = new List<string>();
 // fill payrollnumbers ...
 var currpayrollIndex = payrollnumbers.IndexOf(currpayrollnumber);
 var nextPayrollIndex = currpayrollIndex++;
 var payrollnumber = payrollnumbers[nextPayrollIndex];
```

Comment: so this code not works?

Comment: use `++currpayrollIndex;` instead of `currpayrollIndex++;` btw is using `LinkedList<T>` an option? That would make more sense. You can just use `LinkedListNode<T>.Next` property then.

Comment: Besides, it seems safer to store the current index, rather than the current value, in case of repeated values

Comment: @TimSchmelter [There is a huge difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729).

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using the postfix increment operator (`i++`) the original value is what gets assigned to `nextPayrollIndex` before `currpayrollIndex` is incremented.  You could use the prefix increment operator (`++i`) instead, but I would suggest either making it explicit that you are adding 1 and not increment `currpayrollIndex` at all.

```
var nextPayrollIndex = currpayrollIndex + 1;
```

Or just increment `currpayrollIndex` and use it instead of `nextPayrollIndex`.

```
currpayrollIndex++;
var payrollnumber = payrollnumbers[currpayrollIndex];
```

I'd also suggest adding checks for when the `currpayrollnumber` is not in the list (`IndexOf` will return -1) and when it's the last item (to avoid an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use `++currpayrollIndex` instead of `currpayrollIndex++`:

```
var nextPayrollIndex = ++currpayrollIndex;
```

You can also remove that line entirely and put it in when you access the array:

```
var payrollnumber = payrollnumbers[++currpayrollIndex];
```

However it's very unreadable, and might not be noticed by people skimming over the code

Answer (score 1):

You have to change:

```
 var nextPayrollIndex = currpayrollIndex++;
```

to

```
var nextPayrollIndex = ++currpayrollIndex;
```

Is Your solution `currpayrollIndex` value is increase by 1 **after assign** to `nextPayrollIndex` variable

When You change the moment of increase  `currpayrollIndex` by 1 -  You first increase by 1 `currpayrollIndex` value  and **next assign**  to `nextPayrollIndex` variable

It is good explanation here:

[What is the difference between i++ and ++i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729)

Also You may want to change You code to this:

```
var currpayrollIndex = payrollnumbers.IndexOf(currpayrollnumber);
var payrollnumber = payrollnumbers[++currpayrollIndex ];
```

it will by more readable