# C# '++' Operator in conjunction with ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I needed to verify this in linqpad but this code evaluates to 0 the first time. Why does this occur in C#?

```
var integer = 0;
while(true){
    var @string = integer++.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(@string);
}
```

I also verified that evaluates to 1 first.

```
var integer = 0;
while(true){
    var @string = (++integer).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(@string);
}
```

I get the difference between ++x and x++. just was expecting it to do x++ and then the ToString() gets called.

Comment: Has nothing to do with ToString(). Consult a decent C# tutorial or reference before asking here.

Comment: have a look here to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i

Comment: You mean "why does this code operate correctly in c#"? Please clarify what you expected and why you expected it.

Comment: I expected this to occur. integer = 0; integer++ //integer now is 1; integer.ToString(); //evaluates to a 1.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is getting downvoted.  He is not asking for the difference between post and pre increment.  He is asking for an explanation for what appears to be unexpected behavior, namely, that he expected the `ToString` method to be called after `i` was incremented.

Comment: That is not unexpected behavior. It is another good reason to avoid `++` in expressions.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway `that he expected the ToString method to be called after i was incremented`  It *is* called after `i` is incremented.  To claim that it's not is to not understand what the pre/post increment operators do.

Comment: @Servy - But the `ToString` method does not operate on the incremented value of `integer`.  It operates on the previous value of `integer`.  That's what I meant.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway It operates on the value that the `++` operator evaluates to, as is defined by its specs.  The code would be the same if you didn't call `ToString` and just held the integer result in a variable.  At the end of the day the question is fundamentally asking what the `++` operators do; it asserts that it understands them and then immediately follows it by asking what they do.

Comment: @Servy - I get what you're saying, but when I look at the IL of a simple example (see my answer), unless I am reading it wrong, the value of `i` gets incremented (via the `add` instruction) _before_ the call to `ToString` which operates on a copy of `i`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes, the variable is incremented before `ToString` is called.  That's what I specifically said in response to you asserting the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the post increment operator is that it first saves the value of the variable (`i` in this case), increments `i` and then uses the saved value (in this example, in the call to `ToString()`).

This code:

```
int i = 5;
string s = i++.ToString();
```

is equivalent to:

```
int i = 5;
int temp = i;
i = i + 1;
var s = temp.ToString();
```

You can use LinqPad or other tool (ILSpy, etc.) to look at the IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0004:  dup         
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0006:  add         
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0008:  stloc.2     // CS$0$0000
IL_0009:  ldloca.s    02 // CS$0$0000
IL_000B:  call        System.Int32.ToString
IL_0010:  stloc.1     // s
IL_0011:  ret
```

Here's a [blog post by Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/10/precedence-vs-order-redux/) with more information

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be appreciated.

Comment: If you read your own linked article you'd see that your representation of the order of the operations is wrong.  In fact, it's specifically called out by Eric as being the incorrect way to think of it.

Comment: @Servy - Does my edit more accurately reflect how it works?  I'd appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Your text description of what is happening also needs to be updated.

Comment: The description is correct for a post increment, but not a pre increment, and yet you claim that it applies to both.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, the behavior of the `++` operator in `i++.ToString()` is no different from its behavior when calling any other function that takes `i` as a parameter. For example, you would fully expect the original value of `i` to be passed if you called `SomeFunction(i++)`.

Consider, for example, an extension method:

```
public static class GoofyExtensions
{
    public static string Frob(this int x)
    {
        return x.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, that can be called as if it were an instance method:

```
var s = i++.Frob();
```

The compiler turns that into a call to the static `Frob` method:

```
var s = GoofyExtensions.Frob(i++);
```

It would be pretty surprising to find that `i++.Frob()` returned a different value than `i++.ToString()`.

The point here is that although `ToString()` is a method without parameters, internally all instance methods have an implicit parameter: the instance. If you examine the generated MSIL, you'll see that a reference to the instance is passed as a parameter to all instance methods. So `i.ToString()` is in a very real sense a call to `Int32.ToString(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

The postfix version of ++ returns the value of the integer and then increments, whereas the prefix version of ++ increments then returns.  So in both cases you're calling ToString on the returned value, but the positioning of the operator is what determines which value is being returned.

Comment: i get the difference between ++x and x++. just was expecting it to do x++ and then the ToString() gets called.

Comment: To elaborate on Matt's additional comments, the call to `integer++` returns an Integer object which is separate from the one stored in memory.  The behavior you were expecting was probably more like `integer++; integer.ToString();`

Comment: As an interesting example, in the following code:

`int i=0;
int j=i++;
int k=j++;`

The value of k winds up being 0.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these operators, postfix and prefix, act as functions.  They return a value after performing an operation on their parameter, in this case `integer`.  It is unconventional looking, but that's what it is doing.

So essentially, you're doing:

```
var @string = postfixplusplus(integer).ToString();
```

I hope this way of thinking explains a little bit.

Comment: i get the difference between ++x and x++. just was expecting it to do x++ and then the ToString() gets called.

Comment: These operators act as functions essentially.  Rather than thinking it to do x++, think of it as calling ++ on x and returning a value to the ToString().

Comment: I updated my post to include that, let me know if that helps.