# beginner on c# on The while Loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

```
int num = 0;
while(num < 6) 
{
Console.WriteLine(num);
num++; 
}


int num = 0
while(num++ < 6) 
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

I stuck on this ,
can't tell the difference,
can anyone step by step, plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only a difference in printing, as pointed out in the comments. In the first case **num** is first printed then increased, in the second case it is the other way round.

The first block of code just has a clearer style.

In both cases **num** starts out as 0. The while loop runs until **num < 6**. The statement **Console.WriteLine(num);** prints the current value of **num**.

The tricky, maybe confusing, part is the **num++** statement. It first generates a copy of **num**, then increases **num** and returns the copy.
If it is used standalone in a line, it simply increases the variable.

In the case of **num++ < 6**, First a copy of **num'** of **num** is created, then **num** is increased, and the statement **num++ < 6** is evaluated with the copy (**num' < 6**).

The second loop omit the braces **{ }** thus only encompasses the next statement.

Comment: There *is* a difference in printing.

Answer (score 2):

On the first one you're condition is **If num is less than 6 keep going on**, and then on the loop you add one to num. So the output will be: 0 1 2 3 4 5

On the second case you're condition is the same, because **it's only going to increment num after** that statment. So the output will be: 1 2 3 4 5 6

If you want it the condition to be **If num + 1 is less than 6 keep going on**, do
`while(++num < 6)`

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: For #2, I would note that since there is only one line of code to execute after the true/false check for the while loop, adding the executed statement the line below the while is the same as using brackets, but can only be applied to the immediately following line. It's hard to explain in words, haha

Comment: @MarkC. I had to double read what you said, but you're right ^^. while(num++ < 6) in this case is the same as while(num < 6){num++; (...)