# How to add methods and fields to literal objects?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, literals

In object-oriented programming, everything is supposed to be an object. Starting from this postula, is it possible to add methods and fields to a literal object, such as a number, a string, a Boolean value or a character?

I noticed that in C#, we can use some methods and fields of the "Integer" class from a mathematical expression:

```
var a = (2 + 2).ToString();
```

I imagine that it is more syntactic sugar to access the "Integer" class and a method actually related to the mathematical expression (and / or its value).

But is it possible in C# to define one of the methods and fields to a literal object alone? Such as these examples:

```
"Hello, world!".print();
var foo = 9.increment();
```

This would probably be useless, but the language being object-oriented, this should be feasible. If this is not possible in C#, how could we do this with the object-oriented paradigm?

Comment: FYI: Not everything in C# (.NET) is an object. .NET has reference types (from which object instances can be created), and value types (from which you can't create object instances). However, value types can be boxed (wrapped) in objects, which for example allows value types to be passed to methods as arguments of type `Object` (this is being handled automatically)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here - `2` is an int, so `2 + 2` is also an int. `"Hello, world!"` is a string just like the `s` variable in the following code: `string s = "Hello, world!"`

Comment: @elgonzo ["All value types are derived implicitly from the System.ValueType."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) which inherits from ---> System.Object....
However, the references them selves are neither reference types nor value types - and the same goes for the language's structures such as loops, conditions etc`. So you are correct even if it was for the wrong reasons :-)

Comment: @elgonzo You most certainly can have instances of a value type.  In fact, every variable of a value type has an instance in it. It can't not.  The only types in C# that aren't objects are pointers, and I think maybe one other fringe type.  But basically all types are objects.

Comment: Okay, my first comment is indeed incorrect. I'll keep it around so that the comments of ZoharPeled and Servy are not out of context. My apologies, my bad...

Comment: Isn't it Ironic that the wrong answer was the only one not downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can implement an *extension method* and have the *desired syntax* (however, `Int32` class will **not** be changed):

```
  public static class IntExtensions {
    public static int increment(this int value) {
      return value + 1; 
    }
  }

 ...

 // Syntax sugar: the actual call is "int foo = IntExtensions.increment(9);"
 var foo = 9.increment();
```

In the current C# version (7.2) we can't add *extension properties*, *extension events* etc. These options can appear in **C# 8.0** (Extension everything, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt829270.aspx):

Answer (score 1):

You don't add methods to a given instance of an object, you add methods to a *type*.  Additionally, the language doesn't allow you to define what methods a string (or other type of) literal has, it defines what methods *all* strings have, of which string literals act just like any non-literal strings, and have exactly the same methods.

Note that `(2 + 2)` is not an instance of the "Integer" class, it will resolve to an instance of the `System.Int32` *struct*.  The difference isn't relevant to this behavior, but it's relevant to lots of others.

Comment: And to be even more accurate, it's not the c# language that define the members of string, int, or any other type built in the framework - it's the framework class library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension methods to achieve this, which must be static methods defined in a static class. In you example above, you could do the following:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int increment(this int num)
    {
        return ++num;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would return the original num and only afterwards increase it by 1. In your case it should be ++num. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i

Answer (score 0):

```
"Hello, world!".print();
```

This string is an instance of the String Class in C# which inherits from the Object class. So you have to create the print() method in the String Class in order to make this work.

Comment: Sorry, but we *can't*: both `String` and `Int32` are *sealed*, that's why they can't be *inherired* like `public class MyString: String {public void print() {...}}`. Both  `String` and `Int32` are classes of the standard library which we should not change.

Comment: Yeah, should have mentioned explicitly that that was not possible.