# Is there any difference in using pre increment and post increment in repetition control statements?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int sum , x;
  x = 1;
  sum = 0;

  while(x <= 10){
    sum = sum + x;
    ++x;
   }

  printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

I am learning C and putting together some examples using post increment and pre increment statements. In this example, the output is 55. When I use post increment `x++;` I also get 55. I was actually expecting to get a different answer. Can someone explain why I am getting the same answer. 
and how is this code any different from putting the post/pre increment above the `sum = sum +x;`  expression

Comment: There's no difference if you don't assign the result anywhere.

Comment: Usually, it takes less instructions to perform a ++x as compared to x++.  However, the circumstances of where/how it is used can also have an affect on the resulting efficiency

Comment: x++; and ++x have the same side effect. The only difference is what they evaluate to (i.e., x before the increment or x after the increment). If you throw that value away, there's no difference. The standard says that expressions statements (such as `++x;`) and the last expression in `for` are evaluated as `void` expression. That means the value is discardes, and then there's no difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Answer (score 3):

`x++` and `++x` both add `1` to `x`. The only difference between them is the value of the expression itself, e.g. if you do:

```
y1 = x++;
```

or

```
y2 = ++x;
```

`y1` will get the *old* value of `x`, while `y2` will get the *new* value of `x`. See [What is the difference between i++ and ++i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Since you don't assign the result of the expression to anything, the difference is irrelevant in your program. If you had written:

```
sum = sum + ++x;
```

you would get a different result than

```
sum = sum + x++;
```

since now you're using the value of the expression, and the result matters.

Regarding your second question, statements are executed in order. So if you put `++x;` before the assignment, then you'll be adding the incremented values of `x` to `sum` instead of the original values. Instead of adding `1`, `2`, `3`, ... `10`, you'll add `2`, `3`, `4`, ..., `11`. You can see this difference if you put:

```
printf("Adding %d + %d\n", sum, x);
```

before the assignment.

Putting the increment statement before or after the assignment is similar to using the increment expression in the assignment itself, and choosing between pre-increment and post-increment. I.e.

```
++x; // or x++;
sum = sum + x;
```

is the same as

```
sum = sum + ++x;
```

Conversely,

```
sum = sum + x;
++x; // or x++;
```

is the same as

```
sum = sum + x++;
```

Answer (score 1):

In **C**, not unless you write something complex, such as `for ( int i = 1; sum < bound; sum += i++ )`.

In **C++** with overloaded operators, there can be. `++instance` is generally more efficient than `instance++`, which needs to make a temporary copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int y = x++;
    int z = ++x;
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", x, y, z);
}
```

returns

```
7, 5, 7
```

They all increment x. The difference is the value that's returned.

++x returns x before the increment

x++ returns x after the increment

Answer (score 0):

A pre-increment operator `++x` increases the value of a variable before using it in a expression.In  Post-Increment operator `x++`, value is first used in a expression and then incremented.
if you want to see the difference you can try using `printf()` inside while loop for `++x` and `x++`

```
while(x <= 10){
    sum = sum + x;
    printf("The sum is: %d\n", ++x);
}
```

This will print from number **2 to 11**

```
while(x <= 10){
    sum = sum + x;
    printf("The sum is: %d\n", x++);
}
```

This wil print from **1 to 10**

Another differences are in precedence and associativity. Precedence of **postfix `++`** is more than **prefix `++`**.
 Associativity of **postfix `++`** is left to right and associativity of **prefix `++`** is right to left.

Answer (score -6):

```
sum=sum + ++x; 
sum=sum + x++;
```

This is what you need

Comment: Why does he need this? He asked a question about how it works, not how to get a specific result.

Comment: Only in this case,the sum’s value are difference, There is not difference in sum = sum + x; and then call x++or++x