# What`s the reason for the different results in the while loops?

Tags: c

I have the following C block of code with two while loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;

    while (a++ <= 3)
    {
        printf("cycle a = %d\n", a);
    }

    while (++b <= 3)
    {
        printf("cyclo b = %d\n", b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output for the first while is:

```
ciclo a = 1
ciclo a = 2
ciclo a = 3
ciclo a = 4
```

The output for the second while is:

```
ciclo b = 1
ciclo b = 2
ciclo b = 3
```

What`s the reason for the different results in the while loops?

Comment: [Pre vs. Post increment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec).

Comment: This seems like some kind of homework. Just copying the homework question here is unlikely to get good reception. Instead, you should ask about something _you_ don't understand, explain how _you_ are stumped with this question, and what you have thought.

Comment: Do these answer your question?: [Difference between pre-increment and post-increment in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-loop); [Is there any difference in using pre increment and post increment in repetition control statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877953/is-there-any-difference-in-using-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-repetition); [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: @hyde This is not a homework. I am reproducing a problem that I faced, and would like to know the reason, simple as that.

Comment: Sadly, rarely is an accurate description (caveats, nuance, et'al) of postfix operators in an expression context portrayed, and unfortunately the answers below are no exception to that snake pit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to understand how post-increment and pre-increment operator ++ works.

`while (a++ <= 3)`

Here post increment is used, meaning condition is checked first and the `a` is incremented.

`while (++b <= 3)`

Pre-increment: b is incremented and condition is checked later.

You can see now that, why first loop output is different than the second.

Answer (score 2):

First one is postfix increment, second one is prefix increment. You can check the while condition like this;

```
a++ <= 3(Firstly check a and increment a value)
Check   Output

0<=3     1
1<=3     2
2<=3     3
3<=3     4

++b <= 3(Firstly increment value and check b)

Check   Output

1<=3     1
2<=3     2
3<=3     3
```