# Pre Increment of an operator

Tags: c#

I dont understand why the value of i and k is still 5 in line number 19 ,20,after post increment?

The value of i is still 5 though after post increment.

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Increment
{
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 5;
            int j = 10;
            Console.WriteLine("before incrementing{0}",i);    
             i=i++;    
            Console.WriteLine("after incrementing {0}",i);   //i=5? 
             int k = i;    
    Console.WriteLine("after incrementing i and assign {0}", k);//K=5?
}
    }
}`
```

Comment: Is this just experimentation to see what happens, or an example of a bug? If a bug, just use `i++` instead of `i=i++`. If experimentation then Andrews answer below covers it better than I would have :p.

Comment: You can just write `++i;`.

Comment: [What is the difference between i++ and ++i](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/7444103)

Answer (score 5):

Imagine post-increment and pre-increment as functions:

```
 int PreIncrement(ref int i)
 {
     i = i + 1;
     return i;
 }

 int PostIncrement(ref int i)
 {
     int valueBefore = i;
     i = i + 1;
     return valueBefore;
 }
```

In this case

```
i = i++;
```

would be the equivalent of

```
i = PostIncrement(ref i);
```

You are performing two actions, in this order:

- Incrementing `i`
- Setting `i` to equal the value it equalled before it was incremented

Comment: I think the actual reason is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#simple-assignment (right side evaluated completely before assignment), but this explanation is visual enough to see why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-) for `++` has reasonably clear examples. "The result of `x++` is the value of `x` before the operation, as the following example shows... ."

That means however you use `x++` in an expression you will be getting the initial value, i.e. prior to `x` being incremented. So if `x` is `4` then the value `4` will be used in the expression and `x` will be incremented to `5`. If the expression's value is assigned to a variable then the variable is set to `4`. You happen to have chosen `x` as the target of the assignment, thus overwriting the post-incremented value.