# Printing result of increment (x++) returns original value instead of incremented one

Tags: c#, char, increment

```
        string text = "hello";

        char[] ch = text.ToCharArray();
        
        for (var x=0; x<text.Length; x++)
        {
            Console.Write(ch[x]++); 
        }
```

This is my current code which produces "hello" as output.

Expecting output to be "ifmmp" as every character is incremented by 1.

Comment: You just need to create a new string from the char array after the loop like `var result = new string(ch);` or alternatively do `Console.Write(++ch[x]);` so you'll increment the char before printing it.

Comment: @juharr Please answer in the answer section

Comment: What do you expect a `z` to become? A `{`?

Comment: Related question (with regards to incrementing values): [What is the difference between i++ and ++i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between i++ and ++i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing and incrementing at the same time, try first incrementing, then writing

```
for (x=0; x<text.Length; x++){
            ch[x]++;
            Console.Write(ch[x]);
        }
```

Comment: Why not `Console.Write(++ch[x])`?

Comment: @John relying on side effects of `++` is generally risky - any change to the code can change the behavior. It is far easier to reason about the code when one does not do so. I.e. GO simply does not return values from increment to avoid that whole confusion - https://golang.org/doc/faq#inc_dec

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I thought that `++x` vs `x++` was defined behaviour in C-style languages? I agree that it's easier to follow the code when things are more explicitly written though.

Comment: @John it is mostly defined... like `++x++ - ++x++` I believe allowed to be -1,0,1 based on phase of the moon in C/C++... Or change from OP's code to one shown in this post - just inlinining that x++ to the Write - pretty innocent and easy to overlook. There is also need to make sure it was not misplaced `]` during code review - `ch[x]++` vs. `ch[x++]` ... just not really worth learning all defined and more importantly undefined behaviors associated with return values.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you have LINQ OCD

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(text.Select(x => ++x)));
```